# Mean.io: Redirect to desired route after authentication

Tags: angularjs, mean.io

I have some routes in a mean.io app that require login and I use the

```
resolve: {loggedIn: checkLoggedin}.
```

How do I **redirect back to that route** when the user is authenticated, so that the user don't end up back at the home '/' url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it was to modify the `checkLoggedIn` function so that when it redirects to `/login`, it passes a query string parameter called `redirect` with the path to redirect to. Then, in the `/login` route, add the following function:

```
app.route('/login')
    .all(passport.authenticate('basic'), function(req, res) {
        res.redirect(req.query.redirect);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To fill out on the answer from taylorthomas

In my package routes, add a query string to the url

```
var checkLoggedin = function($q, $timeout, $http, $location) {
        // Initialize a new promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var path = $location.path();

        // Make an AJAX call to check if the user is logged in
        $http.get('/loggedin').success(function(user) {
            // Authenticated
            if (user !== '0') $timeout(deferred.resolve);

            // Not Authenticated
            else {
                $timeout(deferred.reject);
                // $location.url('/auth/login'+'?redirect='+path);
                $location.url('/auth/login').search('redirect', path);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

in packages/users/public/controllers/meanUser.js add the redirect to the call to the servers /login

```
angular.module('mean.users')
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
        // This object will be filled by the form
        $scope.user = {};
        var query = $location.search();

        // Register the login() function
        $scope.login = function() {
            var url = '/login';
            if (query.redirect) {
                url = '/login?redirect=' + query.redirect;
            }
            $http.post(url, {
                email: $scope.user.email,
                password: $scope.user.password
            })
            .success(function(response) {
                // authentication OK
                $scope.loginError = 0;
                $rootScope.user = response.user;
                $rootScope.$emit('loggedin');
                if (response.redirect) {
                    if (window.location.href === response.redirect) {
                        //This is so an admin user will get full admin page
                        window.location.reload();
                    } else {
                        window.location = response.redirect;
                    }
                } else {
                    $location.url('/');
                }
            })
            .error(function() {
                $scope.loginerror = 'Authentication failed.';
            });
        };
    }
])
```

in packages/users/server/routes/users.js add /#! to the redirect query

```
app.route('/login')
    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureFlash: true
    }), function(req, res) {
        if (req.query.hasOwnProperty('redirect')) {
            // res.redirect(req.query.redirect);
            var redirect = '/#!' + req.query.redirect;
            res.send({
                user: req.user,
                redirect: redirect
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                user: req.user,
                redirect: (req.user.roles.indexOf('admin') !== -1) ? req.get('referer') : false
            });
        }
    });
```